# kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlinx.serialization

I am pulling a word json file data from my asset file. then I try to save these data in my room database. I 'm gonna read these data from room after I save. this is my plan but I have a error.

I will share my error and codes below

This json file looks like this

**My word json file in asset folder**

```
[
  {
    "words": [
      {
        "word": "the",
        "meaning": " “The sky is blue.” "
      },
      {
        "word": "be",
        "meaning": "be – “Will you be my friend?”"
      },
      {
        "word": "and",
        "meaning": "and – “You and I will always be friends.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "of",
        "meaning": "of – “Today is the first of November.”"
      },
```

**ERROR**

and I get the following error while processing it.

```
 kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Field 'words' is required for type with serial name 'com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.locale.datamodel.WordsItem', but it was missing
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.PluginExceptionsKt.throwMissingFieldException(PluginExceptions.kt:20)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.locale.datamodel.WordsItem.<init>(Word.kt:19)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.locale.datamodel.WordsItem$$serializer.deserialize(Word.kt:19)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.locale.datamodel.WordsItem$$serializer.deserialize(Word.kt:19)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:36)
        at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(AbstractDecoder.kt:43)
        at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(AbstractDecoder.kt:70)
        at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.CompositeDecoder$DefaultImpls.decodeSerializableElement$default(Decoding.kt:535)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.ListLikeSerializer.readElement(CollectionSerializers.kt:80)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.readElement$default(CollectionSerializers.kt:51)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.merge(CollectionSerializers.kt:36)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:43)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:36)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.locale.datamodel.WordDataModel$$serializer.deserialize-hOmtatA(Word.kt:11)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.locale.datamodel.WordDataModel$$serializer.deserialize(Word.kt:11)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:36)
        at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:100)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.locale.datasource.AssetDataSource.getCommonWords-hOmtatA(AssetsDataSource.kt:109)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.data.repository.WordRepositoryImpl.initData(WordRepositoryImpl.kt:24)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.domain.use_case.commonword.insert.InsertCommonWordUseCase.insertCommonWord(InsertCommonWordUseCase.kt:13)
        at com.enestigli.dictionaryapp.presentation.SplashScreen.SplashScreenViewModel$insertAllDataToRoomDb$1.invokeSuspend(SplashScreenViewModel.kt:41)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@c7efc65, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

**my data model for word**

```
@JvmInline
@Serializable
value class WordDataModel(
    val allData : List<WordsItem>
)



@Serializable
data class WordsItem(
    val words: List<CommonWords>
) {
    fun toEntity() = CommonWordEntity(
        words = words
    )

}

@Serializable
data class CommonWords(
   val word:String,
   val meaning:String
)
```

#### Room

##### Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "MostCommonWords")
data class CommonWordEntity(


    @ColumnInfo(name = "commonWord") val words : List<CommonWords>,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid : Int? = null

)
```

##### Dao

```
@Dao
interface CommonWordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MostCommonWords")
    suspend fun getAllWords() : List<CommonWordEntity>


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun initData(word : List<CommonWordEntity> )

}
```

##### Database

```
@Database(
    entities = [CommonWordEntity::class],
    version = 1
)

@TypeConverters(CommonWordConverter::class)
abstract class CommonWordDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val wordDao: CommonWordDao

}
```

#### Repositories

##### WordRepositoryImpl

```
class WordRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val dao: CommonWordDao,
    private val assetDataSource: AssetDataSource
) : WordRepository {


    override suspend fun initData() {

        val wordsList = assetDataSource.getCommonWords().allData
        dao.initData(wordsList.map{it.toEntity()})

    }

   override suspend fun getAllWords() : Flow<List<CommonWords>?> {

        return flow {
            emit(dao.getAllWords().map { it.words}.flatten())
        }

    }


}
```

##### WordRepository

```
interface WordRepository {

    suspend fun initData()
    suspend fun getAllWords() : Flow<List<CommonWords>?>


}
```

#### Use cases

##### getall

```
class GetAllCommonWordUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WordRepository
){

    suspend fun getAllCommonWord() : Flow<List<CommonWords>?> {

        return repository.getAllWords()
    }
}
```

##### insert room

```
class InsertCommonWordUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WordRepository
) {
    suspend fun insertCommonWord() {

        repository.initData()
    }
}
```

I think everything is correct but I think `my data model` may not be quite correct, based on the error because the error is caused by `words`. There seems to be no mistake between the naming in the json file and the naming in `my data model`. Unfortunately I couldn't find the problem. What can be the problem ?

**EDIT**

**Normal json file**

```
[
      {
        "word": "the",
        "meaning": " “The sky is blue.” "
      },
      {
        "word": "be",
        "meaning": "be – “Will you be my friend?”"
      },
      {
        "word": "and",
        "meaning": "and – “You and I will always be friends.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "of",
        "meaning": "of – “Today is the first of November.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "a",
        "meaning": "a – “I saw a bear today.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "in",
        "meaning": "in – “She is in her room.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "to",
        "meaning": "to – “Let’s go to the park.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "have",
        "meaning": "have – “I have a few questions.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "too",
        "meaning": "too – “I like her too.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "it",
        "meaning": "it – “It is sunny outside.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "I",
        "meaning": "I – “I really like it here.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "that",
        "meaning": "that – “That door is open.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "for",
        "meaning": "for – “This letter is for you.”"
      },
      {
        "word": "you",
        "meaning": "you – “You are really nice.”"
      },
```

it continues like this. Accordingly, how can I edit my codes or how can I fix the problem?

**THE ERROR IS SOLVED**

The solution for the error was caused by me. Since normally that json file doesn't have this data. I changed the name of the json file with the correct json file and the problem was solved. it was my mistake. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks that some of the items in your JSON doesn't contain the `words` field and since you don't accept the `val words: List<CommonWords>` to be `null` - you get the exception.

To confirm that, try making it nullable and then check if you still get the exception.

Comment: in this case How should I create a data model ? if I accept null data for words it wont work properly I think.

Comment: We'd have to see the whole JSON, could you provide it?

Comment: There's a lot of data so it's a little hard to put in here. We can think of it as a continuation of the json file I added above.There is only one list of words and there are words and meanings in it, actually I added words list manuelly. I had prepared my data model as above, but there was no list called words. When I encountered such a problem, I added it manually, maybe it would work, but it didn't. I will share the normal json file as an attachment above.

Comment: By the way if I accept val words:List<CommonWords> to be null. I got a error flatten in repositoryImpl. The error is Function invocation 'flatten(...)' expected

Comment: I'm so sorry it was my fault. I wrote wrong json file name when I read data from json file. 
the error is caused by. I 'm so sorry again. By the way your answer is correct @Mieczkoni thanks for your answer.